# templating/partials with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate something similar to a facebook wall type effect and everytime a post is created the wall is updated. I have built out how i would like the css/html to look with php but i want to do it through ajax now.

My question- Is their such a thing as jquery partials? like a view i can push into my html page. As my update statement has gone from

```
sel.prepend('<li id="'+response[i].post_id +'"> ' + response[i].title + '</li>');
```

With my html below it will take a bit more to update the page

Post Appearance
            
                imgs/t_silhouette.jpg"/>
                
                    Users Name
                    title?>
                    
                        img_url?>'/>*/?>
                        img_url?>"/>
                    
                    

                        link?>">link_title?>
                        link_caption?>
                        message?>       
                    
                    
                    
                    /imgs/cog.gif') no-repeat;margin-right:5px;">
                        Like · Comment · 7 March at 19:08 via APPNAME

Comment: you can use a plugin,I think there is a `jQuery template plugin` that does something like it.

Comment: You can also try http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://handlebarsjs.com/  The syntax is very simple. You have to define a template like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="people-template">
  <ul>
    {{#each people}}
        <li >Name: {{name}} : Location: {{location.city}}</li>
    {{/each}}
 </ul>
</script>
```

Then you can use it like

```
 var context= {
   people: [
      { name: "John Doe", location: { city: "Chicago" } },
      { name: "Jane Sinha", location: { city: "New York"} },
      { name: "Name Test", location: { city: "LA"} }  
    ]
  };

var template = Handlebars.compile($("#people-template").text());
var html = template(context);
$(document.body).html(html);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/HSjfR/2/)